# Click Once Deployment - How to add class libraries that have no reference inside the project to be published

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, clickonce

I'm building a WPF application that uses external libraries which are used via reflection **without referencing them** in the main WPF application (the one to be published).

How can I add these libraries to the Click Once Deployment if they're not added as projects references to the main application?

Comment: What if you just add them to the project and mark as **Copy always**?

Comment: Thanks @WiktorZychla! this solved the issue

Comment: I'll post this as an answer if you don't mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What seems to work here (confirmed by the OP) is adding additional files to the project and marking them as **Copy always** so that they are always included when published.